# Syntax error - for loop - bash

Tags: bash

I have a problem with my loops. I'm using bash version 4.1.2.

My code is the following :

```
### List of files to process from the File .txt defined before ###
g=`cat ${AA}.txt | wc -l`

### Number of time the loop has to make calculated with the number of using  cores ###
let h=($g/$nproc)

### Loop using $h ###
for i in (( i = 1; i <= ${h}; i++ )); do

### Loop to asign every core a process ###
for j in (( j = 1; j <= ${nproc}; j++ )); do

command lines to process $file

done

### Wait for every started process to finish ###
wait

done
```

The syntax error I get is :

```
/var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs/1796866.SC: line 57: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs/1796866.SC: line 57: `for i in (( i = 1; i <= h; i++ )); do'
```

Is there a way to write the loops for i and for j differently to make it syntax working? Thanks

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs

Comment: remove `i in` and `j in`

Comment: Please try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking us humans.

Comment: instead of writing your own check whether you have `parallel`, it's already a solved problem.

Comment: tripleee : Thanks for the shellcheck.net I didn't know it.  karakfa : The program I use doesn't have a parallel option. I'm doing parallel using & after the command line to put it in background and I need it to ask it for every cores. I can use 80 or 256 cores the program will always take 1 core. @Andrea Corbellini : I've deleted "i in" and "j in" but I'm getting the error too many options (my list contain 127000 files). Is while loop will be a better option than for loop?

Comment: put `set -x` before `g=..` to see values being set for all variables. Good luck.

Comment: Heh. ``g=`cat ${AA}.txt | wc -l` `` could perhaps be `readarray -t g < ${AA}.txt; g="${#g[@]}"`

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is (for example):

```
for (( i = 1; i <= $h; i++ )); do
```

although most people would write it like this:

```
for (( i = 0; i < $h; i++ )); do
```

While we are about it:

```
g=`cat ${AA}.txt | wc -l`
```

is probably better written as:

```
g=$(wc -l < "$AA.txt")
```

The `$( )` notation is easier to read than `` ` ``

We save a child process

Always quote variables that contain filenames, they might contain embedded whitespace.

Comment: No need to launch subshells to count lines in a file, bash will do that easily using builtins. See my comment on the question for one way to do it.

Comment: @ghoti:  I agree, but the question was about `for` loops, and there are caveats.  `readarray` was available from bash 4 (which the OP is using) but my problem with it is that we have no idea how large the input file is.  If it was too large it could bust memory or (in theory) even the limit on the number of elements in an an array.  It is a list of file names though, so I agree that is unlikely.  Given the level of experience shown by the question, I feel it is more important to correct the too common "piped cat" practice.